# Kotlin Kodein NotFoundException: No binding found for bind<String>() with ?<Fragment>()

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, dependency-injection, kodein

I have a very simple set up. But I am unable to perform any networking within my the fragment that I am using `Kodein` in.

The fragment inflates and handles all interaction but the networking layer dependency is somehow missing because I receive: `NotFoundException: No binding found for bind<String>() with ?<Fragment>()` every time I hit the button that validates the username/password on this LoginFragmnet.

I don’t understand this error because my `Fragment` class doesn’t have any `String` in it’s args/constructor? Or even depend on a `String`.

**My Application class:**

```
...
override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
    import(androidXModule(this@MyApplication))
    bind() from singleton { MyLoginApi(instance(), instance()) }
    bind<LoginDataSource>() with singleton { LoginService(instance()) }
    bind<LoginRepository>() with singleton { LoginRepositoryImpl(instance()) }
}
...
```

**My API**

```
interface MyLoginApi {

    @POST("Account/Login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun login(
        @Field("username") username: String,
        @Field("password") password: String,
        @Field("sessionType") sessionType: String
    ): Call<BaseApiResponse<Login>>

    @GET("Account/Logout")
    fun logout(
        @Query("token") token: String
    ): Call<BaseApiResponse<Any>>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(
            baseUrl: String,
            cache: Cache
        ): MyLoginApi {

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(MyLoginApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginService (The Datasource)**

```
class LoginService(private val api: MyLoginApi) : LoginDataSource {
    private val bus = EventBus.getDefault()

    init {
        bus.register(this)
    }

    override fun requestLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        val call = api.login(username, password, "mobile")
        call.enqueue { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Success -> {

                    result.response.body()?.let {
                        bus.post(LoginResponse(it, username))
                    } ?: bus.post(LoginResponse(IOException("System Error!")))

                }
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    bus.post(LoginResponse(IOException(result.error)))
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**An Abstract Fragment class:**

```
abstract class InjectionFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    final override val kodeinContext = kcontext<Fragment>(this)
    final override val kodein: Kodein by kodein()

    final override val kodeinTrigger: KodeinTrigger?
        get() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) KodeinTrigger() else super.kodeinTrigger

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        kodeinTrigger?.trigger()
    }
}
```

I know this scenario is very trivial, but I’m trying to do this as a test before integrating in the rest of the project. The `Fragment` displays, but for some reason once I try to do a data request it crashes with an error saying:

```
org.kodein.di.Kodein$NotFoundException: No binding found for bind<String>() with ?<Fragment>().? { ? }

module ⁣androidModule {
bind<String>(tag = "packageResourcePath") with contexted<Context>().provider { String }
bind<String>(tag = "packageCodePath") with contexted<Context>().provider { String }
bind<String>(tag = "packageName") with contexted<Context>().provider { String }
}
```

**Update:**
When single stepping through my Fragment it the debugger says that the `Repository` is *"Lazy value not initialized yet.”*

Comment: Where are you declaring / retrieving your strings `packageResourcePath`, `packageCodePath ` and `packageName` ? it seems this what is wrong here i guess, because you need a string to do your network call.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind the *String* "class" with an instance of itself inside the *kodein.lazy* initialization before you bind classes that use instances of *String*

```
  override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
  import(androidXModule(this@MyApplication))

  bind() from singleton {String()}     //   --->  Add THIS line

  bind() from singleton { MyLoginApi(instance(), instance()) }
  bind<LoginDataSource>() with singleton { LoginService(instance()) }
  bind<LoginRepository>() with singleton { LoginRepositoryImpl(instance()) }

  }
    ...
```

You can do that because in this case the constructor of the class *String* is public, but do not take it as final solution since this is not possible with other data types like *Integer*,  as its constructor is private.

The real problem may lay in this binding

```
bind() from singleton { MyLoginApi(instance(), instance()) }
```

The instances inside *MyLoginApi* are instances of strings, and since you do not have an implementation of *MyLoginApi* interface, the *Kodein* library directly tries to find where those instances are defined. So better create MyLoginApiImpl
and then substitute:

```
 bind() from singleton { MyLoginApi(instance(), instance()) }
```

with

```
bind<MyLoginApi>() with singleton { MyLoginApiImpl(instance())}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with `Hilt` it's build upon `Dagger` and easy to use and google is doing a good job maintaining it. I'd suggest others to use `Hilt` as well.